# How to avoid Wechat warning about visiting an external page?

Tags: html, amazon-s3, wechat

I have a site hosted on AWS S3, with CDN managed by Cloudflare. For most purposes the site works fine, but when I try to share it through the social media app WeChat, I get a warning (pictured below) and then the site doesn't render properly. This doesn't happen consistently, but when the warning appears, then the site fails to load properly.

My first line of thought was that the problems might be that the different settings of S3 compared to a more standard Apache server were triggering some security issue in WeChat, and that Cloudflare might fix the problem, but it doesn't seem to have made any difference.

Removing Google Analytics and all CDN-ified resources also doesn't seem to have made any difference.

Any thoughts or input on either weirdness in the WeChat browser's rendering rules or why S3 might be triggering a warning would be greatly appreciated. Running into a bit of a wall here.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried other sites? Doesn't WeChat show the warning for all sites? If it doesn't do it every time your site is visited, maybe it has some sort of cache of sites already visited, in which case your issue may be related to new / returning visitors. Have you tried accessing your site with the cache cleared, all relevant cookies and other site-specific data removed?

Comment: It doesn't show the warning for all sites. There is no warning for www.yahoo.com, www.baidu.com, or even my personal site (doesn't use https, which I thought might be issue). After a lot of trial and error I finally found the issue. I've added an answer below.

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr WeChat shows a warning for certain top-level domains. My site was on a .me tld, which triggered a warning. The page rendering incorrectly is based on the warning (not sure about why these two things are connected)

After messing around with https (security issues) and removing all CDN-ified assets (thought they might be blocking down rendering), and hosting the site in China vs outside of China, I finally stumbled upon this. Nothing else matters. Its just the tld that triggers the warning and causes the rendering problem.